# Point to Polygon nearest distance DS_distance is not using geography index & knn <-> or <#> does not give result in order

Tags: postgis, spatial-database, st-distance, knn

The below query gives result in wrong order.

```
SELECT *, ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-75.66,45.33), 4326 ) , geometry ) / 1609.34 AS distance 
  FROM myTable 
 ORDER BY geometry <#> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-75.66,45.33), 4326 ) LIMIT 1
```

- Index on the geometry & geography exists.
- I have also tried st_distance in order by, results are perfect but It does not use geometry or geography index.
- I have tried st_DWithin but it is also taking time. for a shorter distance, Dwithin is working fine, but in this case, search distance is at least with 5000 miles.

PostGreSQL version: 9.4
No of rows: almost a million.

how knn fits in above scenario?

I have upgraded version from 9.4 to 9.5. It's working Updated working query is:

```
SELECT *, ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-75.66,45.33), 4326 ) , geometry ) / 1609.34 AS distance 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY geometry <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-75.66,45.33), 4326 )::geography LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You have a full table scan query, yet you expect an index to be used? Please [edit] the question to provide all the details usually required in SQL questions: Versions of software, row count and extent of the spatial table(s), indexes created, and the EXPLAIN plan and actual times (in milliseconds) for your queries.

Comment: @Vince: Thanks for enlighting, ill update all the plan soon.

Comment: If you are running PostGIS < 2.2 or PostgreSQL < 9.5, KNN # is not sufficient to guarantee exact distance.  Also you should be using <-> not <#> for true distance in 9.5+, PostGIS 2.2

Comment: @LR1234567: Yes I have upgraded PostgreSQL version from 9.4 to 9.5. and It did work. Thanks.